# bad_alloc with pointers, references and values

Tags: c++

I'm actually very new to c++. I tried to write a function template, passing a parameter as reference.

While doing so I got a std::bad_alloc. So I also tried to pass it as value and even by pointer. I always got a std::bad_alloc, but I'm very sure, the object exists and the adress is correct (checked it with debugger).

My last try was to create the object right in the function. It works, if I use hard-coded data, but not if I pass the data, needed to create the object, as function parameter.

I'm using a specific framework for numeric simulation (http://www.dune-project.org/), so I'm not sure, if example code is helpfull. I just contacted the framework support and they had no idea, where this problem comes from.

I hope anyone could help me or has an idea, how to fix this/work arround!

code example:

```
 template<const int dim, const int k>
int solvePoissonPDE2(int maxlevel, Dune::YaspGrid<dim>& grid)
{
    /*
    * Debugging Notes:
    * function works, if grid, fieldvector, array AND bitset are created inside the function
    * BUT NOT if grid OR the components used to create a grid are passed as reference, value or pointer parameters (SEGMENTATION FAULT)
    */
    try {

        /*// make grid
        Dune::FieldVector<double, dim> L(1.0);
        Dune::array<int, dim> N(Dune::fill_array<int, dim>(1));
        std::bitset<dim> B(false);
        Dune::YaspGrid<dim> grid(L, N, B, 0);*/
        grid.globalRefine(maxlevel - 1);

        // get view
        using GV = typename Dune::YaspGrid<dim>::LeafGridView;
        const GV &gv = grid.leafGridView();


        const int q = 2 * k;
        // make finite element map
        using DF = typename GV::Grid::ctype;
        using FEM = Dune::PDELab::QkLocalFiniteElementMap<GV, DF, double, k>;
        FEM fem(gv);

        BCTypeParam bctype;
        // solve problem
        using Constraints = Dune::PDELab::ConformingDirichletConstraints;
        poisson_driver<GV, FEM, BCTypeParam, Constraints>(gv, fem, "poisson_yasp", bctype, false, q);


        return 0;
    }
    catch (Dune::Exception &e){
        std::cerr << "Dune reported error: " << e << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    catch (std::string &e){
        std::cerr << "An error has been detected: " << e << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e){
        std::cerr << "STL reported error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...){
        std::cerr << "Unknown exception thrown!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }


}
```

all used functions are working and are tested.

Comment: Post real sample, not only description.

Comment: Most likely, you are using either uninitialized or negative values to pass as `x` in `new T [x]`. But without code that replicates the problem, impossible to say. Could of course be that you are simply running out of memory...

Comment: thanks, I posted a sample, but how could I run out of memory if the function works, if I create the same grid inside and outside the function and it works if I use the one created inside, but not with the one outside (passed by reference)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you try to run the code under debugger (gdb on Linux or under the MSVC debugger depending where you use it), or maybe valgrind? The debugger usually stops at the exact point where the exception is being thrown (or you can add a breakpoint to the bad_alloc constructor) so that you can examine the actual state at that point. You can also try to run CppCheck on the code, it found a lot of bugs for me in the past which were not detected by the compiler warnings (like usage of temporaries, dangling pointers/objects etc.).

Comment: `bad_alloc` does not happen as a result of passing a pointer or reference.   It occurs when a dynamic memory allocation fails.   So either some code you haven't shown is dynamically allocating memory, a constructor being invoked is dynamically allocating memory (a possibility as your code appears to be constructing other objects), or [reasonably likely for a C++ newbie] some instance of undefined behaviour - in which any imaginable result is permitted.    For any of those possibilities, the problem is in code you haven't shown.

Comment: @E. Maskovsky: I tried it with gdb, but it has not shown the bug. I'll try it with valgrind and CppCheck.

@ Peter: I'm only wondering, the code works if I use  `Dune::YaspGrid<dim> grid(L, N, B, 0);` 

inside the function but not if i use exactly the same outside (with same parameters) and pass it with `Dune::YaspGrid<dim>& grid`